# ionic issue with utf8 characters

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm facing with the problem that the text displayed in my `<div>` using **ng-bind-html** do not show some characters correctly.

I get data from $.post where my php returns the excerpt using utf8_encode in json format.

The fact is that the original text is:

> Akinori Goto created this gorgeous 3D printed zoetrope that explores the relationship between time and movement. The design won both the Runner-up Grand Prix and the Audience Award at this year’s Spiral Independent Creators Festival in Tokyo.

and what's rendered in my screen is:

> Akinori Goto created this gorgeous 3D printed zoetrope that explores the relationship between time and movement. The design won both the Runner-up Grand Prix and the Audience Award at this yearâ€™s Spiral Independent Creators Festival in Tokyo.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

- Add this to the `<head>` of your HTML page: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- Make sure you're not encoding the string twice! Try removing `utf8_encode` from your PHP script (if the string is already UTF8 encoded you might not need to call that function).

Comment: Hi, I have the meta tag in my index.html and if I remove utf8_encode function in my PHP, it arises an error when using json_encode due to this function need utf8 content.